# Cognito trigger wrong lambda event

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using **UpdateUserAttributes** (AWS JAVA SDK) to update the user email. However, I'm not using the default email sender from Cognito but I'm using the custom email sender which will trigger the Lambda function. I'm facing two issues:

1. Based on AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html 
   The trigger source value should be "**CustomEmailSender_UpdateUserAttribute**" but the value that I see in the cloud watch is always "**CustomEmailSender_VerifyUserAttribute**".
2. I added the key-value to the **clientMetaData** but on the lambda request payload, the **clientMetaData** is always null.

Does anyone have to face these issues? and how did you bypass it?